# Turn a recursive function into a tail recursive one in Scala

Tags: scala, recursion

I have this recursive function :

```
 def series(n: Int): Double = 
 {
   if(n == 1)  
     return 3 
   if (n == 2)
     return 5
   Math.pow(-1, n) * 5 * series(n - 1) + Math.pow(-1, n-1) * 3 * series(n - 2)
 }
```

And I have to turn it into a tail recursive one. I have no idea how to perform this
Thank you

Comment: You can precompute everything not a `series` recursive call. Like `Math.pow(-1, n) * 5` and `Math.pow(-1, n-1) * 3`

Comment: And, I could be wrong, but I don't think you can have tail recursion with external math operations to the recursive call. In other words, `series(n - 1)` must be evaluated before it can be multipled by `Math.pow(-1, n) * 5`

Comment: The pow is just flippigng between + and - depending on whether n is even or odd. It doesn't affect making it tail-recursive.

Comment: @cricket_007 ... yes . this can be written as tail recursive function

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh ... I dont think its `do my homework for me` kind of situation. For newbies its quite hard to make something tail recursive. At first I thought so but later I had to accept its bit hard

Comment: @pamu Sure, with a closure function as you've defined. OP did say "this function", which I assume meant `series(n: Int)`

Comment: @pamu, it's not easy but that's *why* it's an assignment and why it shouldn't be done by posting on SO and having someone answer it for you. Look at the series  - who will want to calculate that, except as an assignment? Nice answer. BTW :)

Comment: @pamu did you not notice the weirdness of the series ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh ... ya got it .. looks like I have taken it too seriously :P

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because do my homework

Answer (score 3):

Tail recursive version of this series is possible. The trick is to keep `current` and `previous` results in the function params.

The `fooSeries` follows bottom up approach first it takes `n = 1` and `n = 2` results as inputs and then calculates the bigger `n` in terms of smaller `n`.

*Notice `helper` takes init value of `counter` as 3 and init `current` is `5`, `previous` is `3`*

```
def fooSeries(n: Int): Double = {

    @scala.annotation.tailrec
    def helper(counter: Int, current: Double, previous: Double): Double = {
      n match {
        case 1 => previous
        case 2 => current
        case _ =>
          if (counter > n) current
          else
            helper(counter + 1, Math.pow(-1, counter) * 5 * current + Math.pow(-1, counter - 1) * 3 * previous, current)
      }
    }

    helper(3, 5, 3)
  }
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> fooSeries(1)
res46: Double = 3.0

scala> series(1)
res47: Double = 3.0

scala> fooSeries(2)
res48: Double = 5.0

scala> series(2)
res49: Double = 5.0

scala> fooSeries(3)
res50: Double = -16.0

scala> series(3)
res51: Double = -16.0

scala> fooSeries(4)
res52: Double = -95.0

scala> series(4)
res53: Double = -95.0

scala> fooSeries(5)
res54: Double = 427.0

scala> series(5)
res55: Double = 427.0

scala> fooSeries(6)
res56: Double = 2420.0

scala> series(6)
res57: Double = 2420.0

scala> fooSeries(11)
res58: Double = -6955321.0

scala> series(11)
res59: Double = -6955321.0
```